# Best way to check if array key exists and is empty string

Tags: php

I have a setter in which I need to pass a value from an array-element with a specific key.

- If the array key does not exist pass `null`
- If the element value is an empty string `''` pass `null`
- If the value is not empty string `'string or int or ...'` - pass the value

What I have is this:

`$obj->setValue(isset($array['a']) ? (!empty(trim($array['a'])) ? $array['a'] : null ) : null );`

Some would argue that its hard to read. So - whats the "clean" way?

Comment: `$obj->setValue(trim($array['a']) ?: null);` . This will throw PHP Notice if key does not exist, but PHP Notice should be suppressed on production environment

Comment: But `" "` will be passed as `""` though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the null coalesce operator (which catches nulls and non-existing keys) with the empty ternary operator (which catches empty values):

```
$obj->setValue($array['a'] ?? null ?: null);
```

Example:

```
$array = [
    'a' => 'foo',
    'b' => '',
];
var_dump($array['a'] ?? null ?: null); // 'foo'
var_dump($array['b'] ?? null ?: null); // null
var_dump($array['c'] ?? null ?: null); // null
```

Comment: Excellent. I was close to that. But why is `$array['b']` working? `$array['b']` is existing so it should fire `''`. Why is `?:` executed though?

Comment: `??` tests against null, which `''` fails, so it passes through. `?:` tests against empty, which `''` passes so it triggers and returns `null` instead.